# How to print out only object values that are true?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript, and am making a simple user verification object. I need a function that will console.log only users who have "isVerified" set to true.

I have tried numerous ways including loops and if statements. The function name is "showVerified" below.

```
var person = {
    info: [],
    displayPerson: function() {
        console.log('People', this.info);
    },
    addPerson: function(age, firstName, lastName) {
        this.info.push({
            age: age,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            isVerified: false
        });
        this.displayPerson();
    },
    deletePerson: function(position) {
        this.info.splice(position, 1);
        this.displayPerson();
    },
    verifyPerson: function(position) {
        this.info[position].isVerified = true;
        this.info[position].firstName = this.info[position].firstName.toUpperCase();
        this.displayPerson();
    },
    showVerified: function() {
        for (var key in this.info) {
            if (this.info.isVerified = true) {
                console.log(this.info.isVerified[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to happen when running showVerified on my person object, is for it to print out ONLY the age, first name, and last name of any person who is verified.

Comment: `this.info.isVerified = true` should be `this.info.isVerified === true`

Comment: a single `=` is an _assignment_ and `===` is a comparison. you can also use a double bang `if(!!this.info.isVerified) `

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking because we don't see the whole code. what is `this.info`? what is `position`?

Comment: The whole code is there. Those are my functions inside my person object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying to change the way you're naming your properties, so the code is a bit clearer.
Try

```
showVerified: function() {
        this.info.filter(x => x.isVerified).forEach(v => console.log(v))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Then accept the answer to close the question ;) lol
Remember to throw in some { } if you need more than a single line inside the forEach().
Like: 


.forEach(v => {

console.log(v)

})

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use filter, you can try this as well

```
this.info.forEach(person => {
   if(person.isVerified){
   console.log(person);
   }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was trying, but failing to do. Thanks for your comment!